# Sorting date using moment angular is not working

Tags: angular, angular-moment

I have a method to sortDate which is called in Angular ts file.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';     
sortDate(a,b){
        const dateIsAfter = moment(a).isAfter(moment(b));
        const dateIsSame = moment(a).isSame(moment(b));
        const dateIsBefore = moment(a).isBefore(moment(b));
        if(dateIsAfter) {
          console.log('Input Date 1 :',a, ' Input Date 2: ',b ,' Returned dateIsAfter:',-1 * this.sortOrder );
          return -1 * this.sortOrder;
        }else if(dateIsBefore) {
          console.log('Input Date 1 :',a, ' Input Date 2: ',b ,' Returned dateIsBefore:',1 * this.sortOrder );
          return 1 * this.sortOrder;
        }else{
          return 0 * this.sortOrder;
        }
      }
```

The sortDate method is called:

```
this.sortDate(new Date(a[column]), new Date(b[column]));
```

My output in console:
[image]

Sorting works perfectly fine for year 2021. But, when trying to verify with 2022 as highlighted Oct 08 2021 should come after Mar 2022. But, it returns First dateisAfter which is incorrect, as a result Mar 2022 which should be above, goes down. Again, everything in Mar 2022 is sorted perfectly fine. Why is this behaviour.

[image]

When using below sortDate() method it works fine in chrome. However it's not working in firefox

```
sortDate(a,b){
       return new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime()
}
```

Output in chrome:
[image]

Output on firefox:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the reason of using moment if you can just compare the dates by transforming them into milliseconds:

```
sortDate(a,b){
// or  return new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime()
       return new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime()
}
```

```js
const dates = [ '03-MAR-2022 13:40:00', '02-MAR-2022 10:21:37', '31-DEC-2021 18:00:00', '31-DEC-2021 18:00:00', '31-DEC-2021 17:03:00', '31-DEC-2021 17:01:02', '31-DEC-2021 17:01:01', '31-DEC-2021 17:00:00', '08-OCT-2021 17:00:00', '08-NOV-2021 17:00:00', '22-DEC-2021 17:00:00', '30-DEC-2021 17:00:00'];

function sortDate(a,b){
    return new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime()
    // or return new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime()
}

dates.sort(sortDate);

console.log(dates);
```

How @MikeOne mentioned, it is not a good choice as it is deprecated, so avoid to use it in the comming projects

Comment: Exactly. Plus, Momentjs is not a good choice anymore anyway.

Comment: Hello @MikeOne, thanks for the comment, I agree with you and updated the answer

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan The above logic is working perfectly fine in chrome. However, it doesn't work in firefox. Why would that happen. I am updating my question

Comment: Hello @likeGreen can you please share the data, that I can test it on my side.

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan { 03-MAR-2022 13:40:00
02-MAR-2022 10:21:37
31-DEC-2021 18:00:00
31-DEC-2021 18:00:00
31-DEC-2021 17:03:00
31-DEC-2021 17:01:02
31-DEC-2021 17:01:01
31-DEC-2021 17:00:00
08-OCT-2021 17:00:00
08-NOV-2021 17:00:00
22-DEC-2021 17:00:00
30-DEC-2021 17:00:00}

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan format of input date is 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'

Comment: @likeGreen thank you, I have tried on my side on Chrome and it works as expected, But on the Firefox I can test tomorrow, will let you know after testing, but I have updated the answer with the working example.

Comment: Hello @likeGreen, I have tested on Firefox as well, it works as expected